# Issue with ldap tests after upgrading apache mina from 2.0.21 to 2.1.3

Tags: java, spring-ldap, apache-mina, apacheds

I have a project that contains apache mina, and i use apacheds, spring-ldap-test for tests,
i upgraded apache mina from 2.0.21 to 2.1.3
When im running my test class i get the following:

```
Exception in thread "pool-4-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SESSION_SECURED
at org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapProtocolHandler.messageReceived(LdapProtocolHandler.java:162)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1015)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1128)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:106)
at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:89)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:541)
at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(UnorderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:493)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and that's totally normal due to changes in the latest version of apache mina
[https://mina.apache.org/mina-project/2.1-vs-2.0.html],
upgrading apacheds libraries to the latest version didn't solve the problem,
this is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-shared</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

It seems to me that this is an issue of compatibility of apacheds and apache mina, even when using latest versions of apacheds, i would like to know if there is anything i can do to fix this issue, thanks in advance.